# Build shows only route not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I built a react app using the `react-router-dom` library. In production everything works fine and I can access all routes. It looks like this:

In my App.js component:

```
// {... all the imports ...}

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Routes
} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
    {...}
    <Routes>
        <Route {...}>
            <Route {...} />
        </Route>
    </Routes>
    {...}
</Router>
```

Means, I have a `BrowserRouter` that routes a main `Route` with some sub-routes.

I tried using the other router components that come with `react-router-dom`. With the `HashRouter` I was able to access all routes but I had two problems:

- Every path after the hostname had to start with `"/#/"` (with which I would be completely fine), but when I accessed another route the state was still the same.
- Also, I don't want to use a server to access the page, I just want to get a folder with some html, javascript and css in which I can open an html document that totally works.

So exactly what should happen when building a react app?

Comment: As name suggest HashRouter, it adds # automatically, and also with HashRouter you are using Client side routing so all routing is happening on client ( web browser ) so your server is not accessing any route, thats what your second concern is.

Comment: The page rendering the React app ***must*** be served to the browser, even when running locally, e.g. `npm start` if using the default create-react-app settings. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] so we can see the router and routes in full (*so we can see why routes aren't reachable*), the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace, and the reproduction steps to reproduce the issue you have (*e.g. what exactly you are doing*). If everything is working in production then what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic example of how you should implement BrowserRouter in react application. You can read the react doc for proper guidelines.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;
const About = () => <h1>About Page</h1>;

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```